# Finding the largest value in a column of a filtered data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Minimal example:

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(Date = as.yearmon(2000 + 1:30/12),
                 x    = 1:30)
```

I want the largest value of Date that corresponds to a year end. I'm almost there, but am getting back a dataframe when what I really want is a single item. I can solve my problem by creating a temporary dataframe and then using base R to find the maximum value in a column as follows

```
df_tmp <- df %>%
            select(Date) %>%
            filter(format(Date, "%m") == '12')

max(df_tmp$Date) 
[1] "Dec 2001"
```

but surely there must be a simpler way that doesn't involve the creation of a temporary data frame. I'm looking to pipe the output of the filter to a command that returns "Dec 2001"

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: `pull()` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the maximum, you could just use `summarize`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(zoo, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(Date = as.yearmon(2000 + 1:30/12),
                 x    = 1:30)
df %>%
  filter(format(Date, "%m") == '12') %>%
  summarize(Date = max(Date)) %>%
  pull()
#> [1] "Dec 2001"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Anticipating what you might want next, you could also insert `group_by(year)` if you want the last date for each year.

Comment: This is terrific. Hadn't thought of it. Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 2):

`arrange` the `Date`, `filter` the rows where month is December and select the last row. `pull` is used to get a vector output from a dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(month(Date) == 12) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  pull(Date)

#[1] "Dec 2001"
```

Non-piped base R solution -

```
max(df$Date[format(df$Date, '%m') == 12])
[1] "Dec 2001"
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried `slice_max(1)` and `slice_min(1)`, and got the wrong answer in both cases - i was trying a variant of `top_n`, which will be deprecated. Thanks for the Base R solution as well, which is simpler. I will use it.

Comment: If you want the maximum, why not just use `summarize`? 

   ``` r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(zoo, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(Date = as.yearmon(2000 + 1:30/12),
                 x    = 1:30)
df %>%
  filter(format(Date, "%m") == '12') %>%
  summarize(Date = max(Date)) %>%
  pull()
#> [1] "Dec 2001"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

df %>%
  filter(month(Date) == 12) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = x) %>%
  extract2("Date")

[1] "Dec 2001"
```

Answer (score 2):

you may also do it in invisible function style, where `.` is not just used an first argument into pipes but instead used as an object directly.  So your temp_df is obviated.

- value till previous pipe is always returned as `.`
- so `{max(.$Date)}` will return your desired value, if added in one more pipe in the end.

```r
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(Date = as.yearmon(2000 + 1:30/12),
                 x    = 1:30)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(Date) %>%
  filter(format(Date, "%m") == '12') %>%
  {max(.$Date)}

#> [1] "Dec 2001"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Except for (4) these create no additional or intermediate data frames, use no packages other than the ones used in the question and use `cycle` to get the month which seems preferable to bringing in a new package for that or the ugliness of converting to character just for this purpose.

dplyr is only used for its pipes in (1) and is not used in the others.

All these reference `df` only once as as opposed to referring to it multiple times.  The former seems more elegant than multiple references.

**1)**  We convert to zoo, extract the times, subset to  the December months and take the last one.  (Add `%>% as.integer` to the pipeline at the end if you just want the integer year, i.e. 2001.)

```
df %>%
  read.zoo %>%
  time %>%
  subset(cycle(.) == 12) %>%
  max
## [1] "Dec 2001"
```

**2)** or without dplyr at all via base 4.1+ pipes

```
df |>
  read.zoo() |>
  time() |>
  Filter(f = \(x) cycle(x) == 12) |>
  max()
## [1] "Dec 2001"
```

**3)** A variation not using pipes.

```
with(df, max(Date[cycle(Date) == 12]))
## [1] "Dec 2001"
```

**3a)** Another variation

```
max(Filter(\(x) cycle(x) == 12, df$Date))
## [1] "Dec 2001"
```

**4)** This uses SQL. `Date` will be represented by the internal form of yearmon class which is year + fraction where Dec corresponds to a fraction of 11/12 so:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select max(Date) Date from df where (12 * Date) % 12 + 1 = 12")[[1]]
## [1] "Dec 2001"
```

Comment: I gave some thought to all the solutions proposed, and still think that the base R solution is the simplest and best. In some cases, the solution isn't as easily understood, and in other cases, it requires additional libraries. That said, thank you all for helping me think through this problem.

Comment: There are no solutions which only need base because yearmon needs zoo.